# Laravel custom validation: only validate input if input given

Tags: laravel, validation, file-upload, image-uploading, customvalidator

So I followed this tutorial to learn how to upload images with Laravel using Vue: [Image upload and validation using Laravel and VueJs](https://medium.com/@jagadeshanh/image-upload-and-validation-using-laravel-and-vuejs-e71e0f094fbb)

Everything works fine, but I want to make the image upload optional. Now the custom validation fails for the `AppServiceProvider`. if it does not have any input then i get this error

> trying to access an attribute inside an array that does not exist. Undefined offset: 1

I could avoid the error by asking

```
if (request('image'))
```

In the controller and applying the validation for the other fields only if no image is given. However, this gets incredibly messy.

So I am looking for a way to get the custom validation rule working if there is no input. Or is that the wrong way?

Here is the custom validation rule:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('image64', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $type = explode('/', explode(':', substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ';')))[1])[1];
        if (in_array($type, $parameters)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    Validator::replacer('image64', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(':values',join(",",$parameters),$message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the `sometimes` rule to your rule list:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
]);
```

In the example above, the email field will only be validated if it is present in the `$data` array.

Reference: [Conditionally Adding Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Comment: Good idea. However, I found this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields Now the problem with that is: it does not work. image is 'null', but it still gives me the error of the other validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides a validation called 'nullable' in case other validation rules should not be run if the given value is null: [A Note On Optional Fields](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)